# Converting a data frame to table

Tags: r

I have a data frame in the following format:

```
 state1     state2     score
   A          A          3
   A          B          13
   A          C          5
   B          A          1
   B          B          0
   B          C          0
   C          A          5
   C          B          6
   C          C          3
```

I would like to convert it to a table:

```
      A     B     C
A     3     13    5 
B     1     0     0
C     5     6     3
```

Is there an easy way of doing this other than manually?

Comment: or a one-liner : `xtabs(score~state1+state2,df)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do this with `xtabs`

```
xtabs(score~state1+state2, df1)
#        state2
#state1  A  B  C
#     A  3 13  5
#     B  1  0  0
#     C  5  6  3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use function `acast` from `library(reshape2)`:

```
data<-data.frame(state1,state2,score)
library(reshape2)
datan<-acast(data,state1 ~ state2)
```